# What is activity of argument in boolean function and the norm of a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, normed-spaces, boolean-algebra

1) I having problem understanding the concepts of activity of specific variable of a boolean function. For instance if we are given

```
F= (x1'x2)XOR(x3 v x4')x5
```

what is the activity of x1 or x3 or combination of x4 and x5?
I just want the procedure for calculating the activities. I couldn't find it anywhere?

So, could you please explain the approach for the given or any arbitrary function?

2)My second problem is how to calculate the norm of a boolean function? and what is the meaning of norm in boolean algebra?

for instance:

```
F= (x1 v x2) XOR x3(x4' v x5')x6'
```

Or any other fancy function. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

**EDIT**

[activity questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RffaX.png)

[norm questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1KkK.png)

And keys: 41)c 42)b 43)b 44)c 50)c 51)b 52)c

Comment: Could you please share some related links or books?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the "activity of a specific variable"?

Also, why do you expect a standard norm to be defined on a Boolean algebra? Do you have a norm on Boolean algebras that you're looking at? A norm tends to mean the same thing, just varying in how it's computed (i.e. satisfies the properties listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition)).

If you can't find the definition of a norm on a Boolean algebra, maybe you can find your own that qualifies as a norm!

Comment: By "specific variable" i mean the activity of x1 or x2 individually.

Comment: I know what specific means - what does "activity" mean?

Comment: this is my question, what is activity and how to calculate it? i saw some questions and they were asking for activities and norm...

Comment: Could you post an example question (maybe from whatever source you are using)?

Comment: I've added some related questions. Thank you for your time.